# I want to use PayFort Sdk in react native with some libraries and getting error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jcenter, payfort

I want to use PayFort in my React Native and luckily I found out two of these libraries 1 is [RN-Payfort-SDK](https://github.com/Simicart/RN-Payfort-SDK) and the other one is  [react-native-payfort-sdk](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-payfort-sdk)
 and I am using it correctly but when I try to run the project both of the libraries throw me the same error

```
Could not find com.victor:lib:1.0.1.
Required by:project :app > project :react-native-payfort-sdk
```

After the error, I try to search a lot about this library and luckily found a problem that this library is not updated to `mavenCenteral()` as you all know `jcenter()` is not working anymore so the question is can someone help me regarding this library or any other method I'll be really thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install `react-native-payfort-sdk` from my fork until this [PR](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-payfort-sdk/pull/11) merge

just edit `package.json`

```
"react-native-payfort-sdk": "https://github.com/nomi9995/react-native-payfort-sdk#fix/victor-lib"
```

after adding this line, just do
`yarn install` or `npm install`

after installing node_modules, you should clear cache from the android studio like this

[image]

Comment: hey do you know how to generate sdk token I failed to do it

Comment: I have done it multiple times cache clear still, it is not working for me. I'm facing this issues. A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-payfort-sdk'.
> Project with path ':FORTSDKv1.5' could not be found in project ':react-native-payfort-sdk'.

Comment: @PratiusDubey did you install payfort SDK from my fork?

Comment: Yes, I have added this package, and it's working fine for iOS.  "react-native-payfort-sdk": "https://github.com/nomi9995/react-native-payfort-sdk#fix/victor-lib",

Comment: Hi, Muhammad, This is an exception coming from the Android.                                A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-payfort-sdk'.
> Project with path ':FORTSDKv1.5' could not be found in project ':react-native-payfort-sdk'.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use jcenter() to resolve the above old libary  com.victor:lib:1.0.1 as JCenter is still readable for old versions. Your application will work unless there is a newer versions of a library that are not available on jcenter

Comment: Yes I tried but not working